# Morphia Embedded concreteClass Map with generics

Tags: java, mongodb, generics, morphia

I have an interface Fruit with a concrete class Orange. Imagine that the Fruit is embedded in a Basket. I would like to avoid having to include the class name in MongoDB, so I wanted to use concreteClass, like this

```
@Embedded(concreteClass = HashMap<Integer, Orange>>)
private Map<Integer, Fruit> contents;
```

concreteClass requires a Class, obviously. How can I represent my HashMap as shown above.

Comment: There are no class literals for parameterized types. Does plain `concreteClass = HashMap.class` work?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is that I need to communicate to Morphia that the Fruit it encounters in that Map should be instantiated as an Orange. What I'm trying to do is avoid putting implementation specifics, Orange in this case, into my application code. I can leave it as fruit, but then Morphia stores the class name with the document(record), which I don't like.

Answer (score 2):

Storing the className is the mechanism Morphia uses to actually know what concrete class to instantiate when getting data from the database, if the className is not stored, the only mechanism we've got left is to specify the concrete class for the type you are embedding, I don't think Morphia provides any other mechanism to handle this, the mechanism provided by Morphia is supposed to be storing the className, as described somewhere in this document: https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/UsingInterfaces about programming to Interfaces.

If we can't do something like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, Orange>
```

It seems we are stuck with:

```
private Map<Integer, Orange> contents;
```

Comment: You're right that I can declare this based on an implementation class, not an interface, but then I'm not working with the interfaces in my code anymore. By declaring private Map<Integer, Orange> contents;, I'm losing the ability to inject and Apple in the future. Right now, allowing Morphia to store the concrete class with the document works, but I had hoped to be able to define it in the code and keep that out of the document in MongoDB.

Comment: Yeah, storing the concrete class with the document brings some serious issues into picture, like getting married to that certain concrete class at a data storage level, it simply doesn't sound right. There should be a way to do it programmatically configuring your DAO or something right before Morphia creates the actual objects, letting you decide the concrete implementation to create, but it seems there is no mechanism in Morphia to do that... yet, aside from storing the className and stating the concrete class. I will keep investigating another solution though, will share if I can find one.